# What is BlackBerry's equivalent to Androids WebView Component?

Tags: android, web-applications, blackberry, webview

Quick question... Does BlackBerry have an equivalent Android WebView Component, or are we forced to use WebWorks?

I'm reading the WebWorks documentation today and it looks like you write html/css/javascript directly within Eclipse (which I use).  However, I would rather have my web app powered using jQuery-Mobile and simply pass the URL to a WebView type component.  Does BB not support a feature like this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Take a look at `net.rim.device.api.browser.field2.BrowserField`. (For pre-5.0 OS, you'll need to use `net.rim.device.api.browser.field.BrowserContentField`).